# Looking for free maze game which allows me to print games with many puzzles at once

Tags: software-recommendation, games

I'm looking for some logic/math/puzzle games that allow me to print many grids (as in many pages with different games).

Comment: That's not something about Ubuntu, just check some website which would allow you to find these type of games

Comment: Check in the Ubuntu Software app too.

Comment: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com is the place to ask.